# The ulimits in tmux pane are not correct

Tags: ssh, tmux

I have changed the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file and set the `nofile` to 4096, and it returns 4096 if I run `ulimits -n` in an ssh session. But after I run tmux in the same session, `ulimit -n` returns 1024, which was the default limit.
I think this limit should be inherited from the session that starts tmux, but it turns out not. Why? And how should I do to change the limit in a tmux session?

Comment: What operating system? What version?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

All the tmux sessions are forked from the same **tmux** process, instead of the shell process that is executing `tmux`. Although I have reopened the tmux session, it is still forked from the old tmux process, which is started before I have changed the `/etc/security/limits.conf` and already running for a while, and sure the old process's children will use the old configuration.